# Can I use "The mike is yours" implicitly?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

Is it necessary when I say: "**The mike is yours, confound me.**" that you really have a microphone, or you should have a microphone?

If yes, then what should I say instead that sentence with the part "**confound me**"?

*A side question*: Does "**confound**" here mean amaze/impress?

Comment: Are you intending this to be insulting, because it is - it's a non-too-subtle put down of someone you don't believe knows what they are talking about. Knowing the context would be really helpful.

Comment: you can say "the floor is yours"

Comment: @Tetsujin It is not an insult, but a friendly (or nearly a friendly) conversation between two people in a public place (a park to be precise).

Comment: It's still really a challenge, rather than a friendly, 'your turn to speak'. Between friends it's fine, but I wouldn't use it outside that environment.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't really see any possible interpretation where this wording could be taken as insulting. In fact, I grinned when I read it. If anything, it sounds complimentary—something that would be said jokingly to a scientist by a layperson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation like a friendly competition such as Karaoke or Rap Battle, you could certainly say

> "The mike is yours, confound me."

figuratively, even if the there is no literal microphone available. Very similar to @djna 's "The floor is yours" comment.

The word "confound" is usually meant to be related to confusion, rather than amazement. Use "amaze me," "impress me," "astound me," (even "wow me") etc. if you're asking someone to impress you.

Comment: So I can use "**The floor is yours**" even if we weren't in Karaoke, but in a park and we are having a normal conversation?

Comment: Yes. "The floor is yours" is used simply to say, "It's your turn to speak."

Comment: I agree that's what the word means, but in the phrase *confound me* I would take it to mean *dazzle me*. Nobody would ever say "Please confuse me."

Comment: @JasonBassford I thought it has two meanings.

Answer (score 1):

On the second part of your question, if this is friendly, confound doesn't mean "impress" in most contexts. As per https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confound it tends to be used for negative aspects, effectively "confuse me, annoy me, frustrate me."

For positives, you may want to substitute something like "Astound me" or "Amaze me" since those, in plain reading, tend to be more positive (as they are mostly just different ways of saying "surprise me"